# amcharts connected to odbc sql

Tags: php, sql, odbc, amcharts

I am rather new in PHP and I want to use the free charts of [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/) on an internal network. Those charts will be connected to an ODBC database.
I found a tutorial explaining [how to connect to "mysql"](https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-data-loader-to-connect-charts-to-mysql-data-base/). 
But I don't know how to modify that code so it would connect to my already existing ODBC database.

I wrote the following code which seems to be working but I just get a "Loading data..." message and nothing else:

DATA.PHP FILE:

```
<?php
// we need this so that PHP does not complain about deprecated functions
error_reporting( 0 );


// Connect to SQL
$link = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=XXXXXXXX;Database=XXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=Yes", "", "");
if ( !$link ) {
  die( 'Could not connect: ' . odbc_error() );
}

// Fetch the data
$query = "
  select distinct last_date,
  count(last_date) as NumberOfBIS
  from [dbo].[xxxxxx]
  group by last_date
  order by last_date";
$result = odbc_exec($link, $query);

// All good?
if ( !$result ) {
  // Nope
  $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . odbc_error() . "\n";
  $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
  die( $message );
}

// Print out rows
$data = array();
while ( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) ) {
$data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );

// Close the connection
odbc_close( $link );
?>
```

HTML FILE:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>amCharts tutorial: Loading external data</title>
  <script src="amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="amcharts/serial.js"></script>
  <script src="amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  <script>
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "data.php"
    },
    "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/",
    "categoryField": "category",
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "startDuration": 1,
    "categoryAxis": {
      "parseDates": true
    },
    "graphs": [ {
      "valueField": "value1",
      "bullet": "round",
      "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
      "lineThickness ": 2,
      "lineAlpha": 0.5
    }, {
      "valueField": "value2",
      "bullet": "round",
      "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
      "lineThickness ": 2,
      "lineAlpha": 0.5
    } ]
  } );
  </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: First, what is your ODBC database -MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2? And the link seems clear that you simply connect to db as you normally do in PHP. Then, query the data, convert to json, echo json on a data.php page that you pass as url in `AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {...`

Comment: Connecting to an odbc database in PHP requires the odbc driver be installed and setup. Is this running from a shared environment (web hosting), vps, or your own computer?

Comment: I am using SQL and I have PHP installed on my computer via XAMP.